# adaptive height is not working on vertical and fade mode in bxslider plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, bxslider

I am working on bx Slider JQuery plugin. I configure `adaptiveHeight: false`. This configuration is working fine on mode as horizontal. But, not working mode as vertical and fade. that slider height is increasing and decreasing based on the slider images, But i want a fixed height.How to fix this issue.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w16z3gt0/1/)

**my configuration is:**

```
$('.slider').bxSlider({
   adaptiveHeight: false,
   auto: false,
   autoControls: false,
   autoDirection: "",
   autoHover: false,
   autoStart: false,
   captions: false,
   easing: "linear",
   hideControlOnEnd: false,
   infiniteLoop: false,
   maxSlides: 1,
   minSlides: 1,
   mode: "vertical",
   nextSelector: "#slider-next",
   nextText: "<img src= style="width:35px;height:35px;"/>",
   pager: false,
   pause: false,
   prevSelector: "#slider-prev",
   prevText: "<img src= style="width:35pxpx;height:35px;"/>",
   randomStart: false,
   slideMargin: 10,
   slideWidth: 150,
   speed: 1000,
   startSlide: 0
});
```

Comment: By default bxSlider will take on the tallest slide's height and set it for every slide thereafter. You need to provide a live demo of what you already have done. So if you say you got it working but the sizes shift, then provide us a demo of it

Comment: here is the Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/w16z3gt0/1/

Answer (score 0):

## **Update**

OP expressed the need to display images of varying heights...but wants a fixed height. So what I gather is a fixed slider height that is able to display images of varying heights in a vertical flow. The challenge as getting the control arrows to stay in one place and be able to adjust according to a resize.

There's too many changes to the CSS to go through each of the reasons they are used for, so we'll go through the most important parts and if there any further questions, that can addressed on a case per case basis.

```
    .box { height: 100vh; overflow-y: scroll; }
    .bx-view-port { height: 100vh; }
```

Because the majority of the world's digital media is horizontally oriented, not enough thought was put into a good UX using a vertical flow I assume. The only height properties in `jquery.bxslider.css` were for icons and the loader. The generated wrapper `bx-view-port` is the main reference for width and height, so keep that in mind when your bxSlider goes to 0 height after a browser update. Adding a wrapper for the whole slider (`.box`) helps stabilize the vertical transitions as well as provide a parent for the next addition, `.bx-nav`.

The most irritating thing to deal with are the arrow controls for previous and next steps. I usually repositioned them to the top because it was the only stable area of the slider when it's in vertical mode. In this demo, we customize the arrow controls:

1. Add these two options to the bxSlider JS/jQ:

   ```
   prevSelector: '.prev',
   nextSelector: '.next',
   ```
2. In the HTML add this under the `bxSlider` element:

   ```
   <nav class="bx-nav">
      <div class="prev"></div>
      <div class="next"></div>
   </nav>
   ```

These steps will establish a new set of controls that are easier to setup, position, and style. You should now have 2 anchors: `PREV` and `NEXT`.

1. Add the following to the bxSlider options:

   ```
   prevText: "<i class='fa fa-nav fa-fw fa-chevron-circle-left'></i>",
   nextText: "<i class='fa fa-nav fa-fw fa-chevron-circle-right'></i>",
   ```
2. Next, add this `<link>` to the `</head>`:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   ```

Now those lame anchors should look similar to the original controls. What we did is write a string that generates a `<i>` (like jQuery's method creating an element with all the attributes and values), and appends to the corresponding element --`.prev` and `.next`. The slick looking font icons are compliments of 
[Font](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/chevron-circle-left/) [Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/chevron-circle-right/).

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/j6DOEcvQA5hbMZvyilNq?p=preview) / [README.md](http://plnkr.co/edit/j6DOEcvQA5hbMZvyilNq?p=info)

**Snippet**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>35788901</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.box { height: 100vh; overflow-y: scroll; }
.bx-view-port { height: 100vh; }
img { margin: 0 auto; }
.bx-nav { position: absolute; width: 356px; height: 48px; top: calc(50% - 24px); left: calc(50% - 178px); margin: 0 auto; }
.prev, .next { position: absolute; width: 48px; line-height: 48px; z-index: 9999; font-size: 48px; opacity: .4; color: #0FF !important; }
.prev:hover, .next:hover { opacity: 1; color: #00D !important; cursor: pointer;}
.prev { left: 0; }
.next { right: 0; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section class="box">
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li> <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150/fff/e00" /> </li>
    <li> <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300/040/fff" /> </li>
    <li> <img src="https://placehold.it/450x150/000/0ff" /> </li>
    <li> <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300/cfc/000" /> </li>
    <li> <img src="https://placehold.it/600x150/040/fff" /> </li>
    <li> <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300/000/fff" /> </li>
  </ul>
  <nav class="bx-nav">
    <div class="prev"></div>
    <div class="next"></div>
  </nav>
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(function () {
  var bx = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'vertical',
    speed: 500,
    slideMargin: 20,
    infiniteLoop: true,
    slideSelector: 'li',
    pager: false,
    prevSelector: '.prev',
    nextSelector: '.next',
    prevText: "<i class='fa fa-nav fa-fw fa-chevron-circle-left'></i>",
    nextText: "<i class='fa fa-nav fa-fw fa-chevron-circle-right'></i>",
    minSlides: 3,
    moveSlides: 1
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

---

Old

```
It looks as if a default height is overlooked when using a vertical mode. I have had problems with height under different circumstances but it looks like my case is not the only configuration having troubles controlling height. Here's the additional CSS I applied to tame bxSlider's height jumping. I also set the `min/maxSlides` to 3. It looks as if the carousel is vertical, it doesn't adjust it's slides according to height of viewport.
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/s33a7su5/)

Comment: If you try with different dimension image height of the slider is increasing and decreasing based on the image(adaptiveHeight:false) @zer00ne

Comment: @kalles please review update, let me know if it doesn't meet requirements or if you have any further questions.